# could not acquire lock on a component

Tags: seam

I get this error sometimes on a session scoped component, still haven't figured out what is causing this to fail. Any ideas?

```
ERROR [Exceptions] handled and logged exception
javax.el.ELException: org.jboss.seam.core.LockTimeoutException: could not acquire lock on @Synchronized component: importUser
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Session scoped components are synchronized by default. That means, Seam takes care that only one request at a time may access such a component. All other requests have to wait until the first is finished. To prevent starvation, the waiting requests have a timeout (see `org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor` for the corresponding implementation). When the waiting request does not get access to the component until the timeout is reached, the `SynchronizationInterceptor` throws a `org.jboss.seam.core.LockTimeoutException`.

Assuming to requests, A and B, need your `importUser` component and A is first. If A takes a long time to finish, B will end in the `LockTimeoutException`. To find the cause of your issue, try to find out how a request to `importUser` may take longer than the defined timeout.

Comment: This doesn't happen because there is a long running command, but seems to surface when there is an Exception being thrown from this method and you are trying to re-access the same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

I had a page where this would happen infrequently under heavy load. I was able to reduce the frequency of this occurring by putting this annotation on the offending Seam object class:

```
@Synchronized(timeout=5000)
```

That increases the timeout to five seconds instead of the default one second Seam gives them. It's just a band-aid, but I wasn't up for rewriting that behemoth.